# Copy Cell B into Cell A, if B contains A

Tags: excel, search, copy, contains

I have two columns with links. Column A needs to be replaced by B.

Both links contain an unique ID, but otherwise do not look alike. (See image)

[image]

The 2 columns will contain thousands of links.
Can I choose column B, and search for the unique ID in Column A, and replace if found?

Comment: your question is not clear can you provide more information and required output ?

Comment: I want to do a search and replace.
Search Cell B2 for the unique ID. Then find the same ID in Column A, and replace entire cell with the entire content of B2.

Comment: Column A&B contains links with a UNIQUE ID. If Column A has an ID that is present in column B, then replace ORIGINAL LINK with NEW LINK